# How do I iterate through a template <typename Template>

Tags: c++, iterator

so I have the following Template struct.

```
template <typename Template>
struct PositionData : public Serializer::ISerializable
{   
Template dataPosition;
    virtual void Serialize(Serializer::IStreamWriter& out) const
    {
        out.Write(L"dataPosition", dataPosition);
    }
    virtual void Deserialize(Serializer::IStreamReader& in)
    {
        in.Read(L"dataPosition", dataPosition);
    }
};

PositionData<std::map<uint32, uint32> >compressedItems;
```

I want to create an iterator for `compressedItems.dataPosition` in order to extract the values that are inside of it. Hence I don't really know what are the `uint32` indexes I need an iterator.

If you guys could give me a briefly explanation that will be awesome.
Thanks.

Comment: If what you are asking for is not  simply `compressedItems.dataposition.begin()` then you need to provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what you are asking. Your question is completely unclear.

Comment: What I'm trying to do basically is iterate thru `compressedItems` which is a variable where I'm storing std::map<uint32 offsets, uint32 value>
If I use an operator[] I can get valid [compressedItems.dataPosition[3295]]
My issue with it is that the index values are not linear so I can't just loop [i]

Comment: My issue is that how do I declare my iterator? 
for ( auto it = compressedItems.dataPosition.begin(); it != compressedItems.dataPosition.end();it++)
  {
   printf("here\n");
  } 
instead of using auto? Can i do it somehow based on T?

Comment: [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) under the section titled *Iterators*.

Comment: If `T` is a container, how would you reference it's iterator? `T::iterator`, or `T::const_iterator` of course. Now, all you have to do is figure out what `T` is in this case. So, here's your final exam: what is the type of `compressedItems.dataPosition`?

Comment: In this case it'll be a std::map<uint32,uint32> map but can't I create a typedef T::iterator? I'm just wondering that because we have possibilities of having templates but I've never seen a T::iterator;

Comment: @Henrique: Of course you can write `typename T::iterator`, but it’s not very common in the age of `auto`, since `begin` (or just a range for) means “iterator” just as much.

Comment: I was trying to use auto but the compiler was yelling at me that's why I was trying to use typename

Comment: Your code is too minimal. You need to provide code that show your problem! Otherwise, you are wasting everyone time by a question that is not answerable.